# compare a element and next element in a list, if they are same then add corresponding index elements value in second list

Tags: c#, list

There are two lists. One has elements 1,1,0,0,0,1 and the second list as elements 200,300,100,200,100,350. I have to compare the list1 element at index with the next index element. if they are same then add elements at same indexes in list 2 and save in some other list.

```
input list1 -> 1,1,0,0,0,1
input list2 -> 200,300,100,200,100,350

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> signalTrans = new List<int>();
            List<double> time = new List<double>();

            List<double> timeSorted = new List<double>();
            List<int> signalTransSorted = new List<int>();

            signalTrans.Add(1);
            signalTrans.Add(1);
            signalTrans.Add(0);
            signalTrans.Add(0);
            signalTrans.Add(0);
            signalTrans.Add(1);

            time.Add(200);
            time.Add(300);
            time.Add(100);
            time.Add(200);
            time.Add(100);
            time.Add(350);

            int i;
            double k;

            for (i = 0; i < signalTrans.Count(); i++)
            {
                if ((i + 1) < signalTrans.Count())
                {
                    if (signalTrans[i + 1] == signalTrans[i])
                    {
                        k = time[i + 1] + time[i];
                        signalTransSorted.Add(signalTrans[i]);
                        timeSorted.Add(k);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                }

            }
        }
    }
}


output list1 -> 1,0,1 
output list2 -> 500,400,350
```

Comment: You've laid out the requirements, but what's your actual question? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: In your example, there are three 0s in a row (indices 2, 3, and 4). Does this mean you add 100+200 (indices 2 and 3) and 200+100 (indices 3 and 4)? Or are you supposed to add all three together?

Comment: @Forty3 The sample outputs are hidden right at the end of the code sample.

Comment: @BrootsWaymb, There are two lists. One has elements 1,1,0,0,0,1 and the second list as elements 200,300,100,200,100,350. I have to compare the list1 element at index with the next index element. if they are same then add elements at same indexes in list 2 and save in some other list.
input list and output list are there in code section at top and bottom.

Comment: @Forty3 all three together

Comment: Sorry for that, this will require me to install package which if at all I do for getting this result its ok for now. But this small piece of code integrates and runs in a large code across the globe on different PC so it has to be always backward compatible.

Comment: You could always copy the MoreLINQ code into your project if you want to avoid referencing the DLL. https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/GroupAdjacent.cs I'll leave it with you to decide on the licensing implications of that decision. Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use [MoreLinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/), I'd suggest starting with:

```
var result = signalTrans.Zip(time, (signalEntry, timeEntry) => new { signalEntry, timeEntry })
    .GroupAdjacent(z => z.signalEntry)
    .Select(z => new { signal = z.Key, totalTime = z.Sum(y => y.timeEntry) });

var indexes = result.Select(z => z.signal).ToList();
var totalTimes = result.Select(z => z.totalTime).ToList();
```

`Zip`is used to zip together the two lists together - so you have an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type containing data from both lists.
`GroupAdjacent` then groups together adjacent entries from `signalTrans`.
`Sum` then adds up the `time` entries.

This results in the output you specify in your question:

> output list1 -> 1,0,1
>
> output list2 -> 500,400,350